# unpack packed scripts with javascript function

Tags: javascript, minify

unpack javascript code with function.js

I need the function and not the online websites for jsbeautifier.

I want to beautifier scripts with our own function.

code for example :

```
<script>
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('8("2q").2p({13:"7://2o.6.5:2n/2m/2l.2k",2j:"7",2i:"4",d:"7://6.5/9/w.p",2h:"2g",2f:2e,2d:2c,2b:"6.5",2a:"",29:{13:\'/28/27.26\',s:\'e\',n:\'25-24\',23:\'22\',12:\'/\'},21:{20:"e",1z:"1y",1x:"e"},1w:{"1v-3":{"12":"7://6.5/r","1u":\'<11 q="7://6.5/1t-r-1s.1r" 1q=0 1p=0 1o=0 1n=1m 1l=1k 1j=1i></11>\'},"/9/1h.1g?1f":{"1e":"r"},"1d-2":{},"1c-1":{}},10:[{g:"v",f:{d:"7://6.5/c/c.u"}},{g:"z",q:"7://6.5/9/9.y",f:{d:"7://6.5/c.p"}}],10:[{g:\'z\',q:"7://6.5/9/9.y",f:{d:"7://6.5/9/w.p"}},{g:\'v\',f:{d:"7://6.5/c/c.u"}}]});o h;o m=0;o a=0;8().1b(b(x){i(a>0)m+=x.n-a;a=x.n;i(0!=0&&m>=0){a=-1;8().1a();8().19(e);$(\'#18\').l();$(\'k.j\').l()}});8().17(b(x){a=-1});8().16(b(x){t(x)});8().15(b(){$(\'k.j\').l()});b t(x){$(\'k.j\').s();i(h)14;h=1}',36,99,'|||||org|youwatch|http|jwplayer|player|p016043|function|lulu|skin|false|config|type|vvplay|if|video_ad|div|show|tt16043|position|var|zip|src|q0dwycezrio5|hide|doPlay|xml|html5|bekle||swf|flash|modes|iframe|link|file|return|onComplete|onPlay|onSeek|video_info_box|setFullscreen|stop|onTime|backstroke|timeslidertooltipplugin|video_id|nocache|js|download|380|HEIGHT|640|WIDTH|NO|SCROLLING|MARGINHEIGHT|MARGINWIDTH|FRAMEBORDER|html|640x380|embed|code|sharing|plugins|oncomplete|none|callout|onpause|viral|_0|linktarget|left|top|png|logo_player|images2|logo|aboutlink|abouttext|650|width|360|height|7895|duration|bufferlength|provider|mp4|video|tlvp43czfwoax3ptxzfinrfyuh4xxzcjmtk2ojth3w2upbsc5dae55p7zy|8777|fs37|setup|flvplayer'.split('|'),0,{})) ;
</script>
```

Something like:

```
var = code
function(unpack(var))
```

Comment: Remove `eval` and run the code.

Comment: Please [search before asking](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+unpacker&rlz=1C9BKJA_enGB590GB590&oq=site&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59l2j0&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en-US). There are many existing questions regarding this.

Comment: I need the function and not the sites online for jsbeautifier

Answer (score -1):

Use [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to beautify the uglified **(obfuscated)** JavaScript.